# XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a JSON file but it returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, json

I am following a guide from w3schools trying to understand JSON better.

This is their code
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_ajax

This is their sample JSON file
https://www.w3schools.com/js/json_demo.txt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>
<p>The content is written in JSON format, and can easily be converted into a JavaScript object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

<p>Take a look at <a href="json_demo.txt" target="_blank">json_demo.txt</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have another example JSON file here that I want to use
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json

Using the same code, apart from changing

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;

to

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj;

It doesn't seem to bring back anything apart from [object object] and I cannot understand why, Could someone please help, thanks

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` produces an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Attempting to [display an `Object` as a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description) produces `[object Object]`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What do you want to print in your `<p id="demo">` element?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the received JSON object to the DOM, you'll need to turn it into a string. To do this, use `JSON.stringify(responseText)`.

Comment: Or just skip parsing the response in the first place